# How to send the arguments to the Class as a decorator?

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I have the following demo script where I have two decorators (nested). One is `validNumber` which is a function return wrapper to test the arguments passed to the decorated function are positive or not and Another one is `addExtra` which is a class to plus the output of the previous decorator with one.

```
def validNumber(f):
    def wrapper(*args):
        for arg in list(args):
            if arg < 0:
                raise AttributeError('The number can\'t be negative')
        return f(*args)
    return wrapper

class addExtra:
    def __init__(self, fun):
        self.fun = fun
    def __call__(self, *args):
        total = self.fun(*args)
        if total < 100:
            total += 1 # I want to make it dynamic.
        return total

@addExtra
@validNumber
def sumOfNumbers(*args):
    return sum(list(args))
```

Now as you can see I manually add '1' to the total of the arguments. But I want to make it dynamic. Like:

```
@addExtra(4) # add 4 to the total
@addExtra(2) # add 2 to the total
```

**UPDATE**
As community suggests another question with a similar problem. I do the following

```
class addExtra:
    def __init__(self, extra):
        self.extra = extra

    def __call__(self, fun):
        @functools.wraps(fun)
        def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
            total = fun(*args)
            if total < 100:
                total += self.extra  # I want to make it dynamic.
            return total
        return decorated
```

and getting

> TypeError: **call**() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given

Can someone please explain here instead of redirect to some other question or answer? Even I also want to know the use of @functools.wraps here.

Comment: Well it return the decorated function object instead of result. i.e <function addExtra.__call__.<locals>.decorated at 0x000001F5D4C3E4C0>

Answer (score -1):

To be able to pass arguments to your decorator you have to create a function that returns a decorator.

```py
def addExtra(number):
    def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
        def wrapper(fun):
            total = fun(*args, **kwargs)
            if total < 100:
                total += number
            return total
        return wrapper
```

Comment: The question is about accepting arguments in the decorator as a class.

Comment: In the way it is written it doesn't change a thing. Moreover what I have posted still holds if you return a class from the method.